# Translating Java RSA encryption routine to Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, security, encryption, rsa

I am trying to duplicate an encryption process that is working in Java over to iOS/OSX.

My Java code is as follows:

```
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").
                    generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(firstKeyInteger, secondKeyInteger));
// This always results in the public key OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=2b3b11f044.....58df890,publicExponent=10001}

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA1ANDMGF1PADDING");
String stringToEncode = "EncodeThisString";
byte[] bytesToEncode = stringToEncode.getBytes("UTF-8");
cipher.init(cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plain);
```

The first challenge i'm struggling with is how to use the public key in iOS. Can I just dump the modulus into NSData and use it? Or must I store it in the keychain first? (I don't really need to use the keychain unless I must). Or is there a method similar to `generatePublic()` were I can recreate the public key using the 2 integers?

Then would I use `SecKeyEncrypt` to encrypt? Whenever I add this to my project I get `Implicit declaration` warnings even though I import the Security framework.

Thanks

EDIT -----
I think I have managed to get a Base64 encoded public key, which I believe is what is in a PEM certificate. Now, how to use it.

Comment: Ever find a solution? Having the same issue..